# Determining if slopes are zero or slopes are equal- can one actually accept a null hypothesis?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I am not a statistician and would like some help discussing best practices with colleagues.

My understanding is that if I run a linear regression
y = ax +b
the p value I get for x is testing HO:a=0 vs H1:a is not zero

If the p value is low enough, I can reject the null hypothesis and assume that the slope is significant. I believe I cannot say that the slope is zero, i.e. accept the null hypothesis.

I am now looking at discussions of using ANCOVA to compare the slopes of two groups. In that case, I add a categorical value to the equation and I will end up with an interaction term which is evaluated via an F test. I will also get a value for Pr(>|F|).

If that is low enough, I can reject the null hypothesis and assume the slopes are different. Everything I have read on-line seems to make the claim that if the value is high, the slopes are the same.

I mostly compare means, in which case, if I cannot reject the null hypothesis, I switch to an equivalence test (TOST) to see if the means are the same within a predefined threshold.

Perhaps, naively, I would have thought the same would apply to testing for zero slope or whether slopes are the same. I am getting a lot of push-back from colleagues who routinely use a t-test to determine if a slope is zero and ANCOVA as above to indicate the slopes are the same. but there are no statisticians in our company.

Maybe I am just caught up in unfamiliar jargon, but a little understanding of how to think about these questions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct that you can never "accept" a null hypothesis. Hypothesis testing can be seen as a "proof by contradiction". If we assume the null and obtain a very rare finding, we say that with some **significance level**, we reject the null (and conclude the alternative when it is the complement of the null). However, when you fail to reject, this definitely gives no reason to accept the null. "Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence".

I would highly recommend you to look into equivalence testing if you want to establish equality means. One useful review paper to look at is the following https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0950329312000961. One approach discussed here is the power approach which says the we can only "accept" the null if we have sufficient power against particular alternatives. If these alternatives would be true, we would have rejected with our test (under a particular significance level). However, this approach also has some drawbacks as discussed by the paper. It also explains TOST in detail and should be possible to follow for non-statisticians.

Comment: Just a quick question. I use TOST for testing for equivalence of means. The question that I am now dealing with is testing either that a slope is zero or that two slopes are the same. I believe the first part of your answer makes it clear that this cannot be done based on not being able to reject the null hypothesis. You then talked about equality of means. Are the approaches for comparing means equally appropriate for slopes?

Comment: Yes I would say so. In the end, both the (underlying) mean and slope are parameters to be estimated. To draw conlusions about the equality of such parameters, not rejecting the null is not sufficient to make a claim. Applying a TOST procedure can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly perform two t-tests. It is sufficient to consider the confidence interval and the three hypotheses

$$\begin{array}{}H_0&:& \text{|difference|} = 0\\
H_\epsilon&:& 0 <\text{|difference|} \leq \epsilon\\
H_\text{effect}&:&  \epsilon < \text{|difference|} \end{array}$$

[image: plot of TOST]

and you can do this for the estimates and confidence intervals of slopes.